# Taking Images From Camera with Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, webcam

I want to help user to take their pictures with a plugged in video camera and post it to the server by using Adobe Flash. is there any component can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a "component" but if you want to try making your own then this might get you started?

[Webcam in flash tutorial](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/326194)